# Date and currency formats wrong on website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I deployed my ASP.NET Core MVC web application written in C# to a production IONOS server. The site runs properly however dates and currency fields display with European format instead of US.

I know it is a culture issue, and I assume it is because of the settings on the host server. How can I change the culture for my website for all users? I don't have access to server settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this and it works if I put in Program.cs after app is created.

```
//-------------------------------
// this sets the culture to us
//-------------------------------
var defaultCulture = "en-US";
IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
{
    new CultureInfo(defaultCulture)
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```